# Is $2\sin^2(2x)$ the same as $(2\sin(2x))*(2\sin(2x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is $2\sin^2(2x)$ the same as $(2\sin(2x))*(2\sin(2x))$?

Comment: That depends on what you want obtain. Linearise?

Comment: No, its equal to $2 (sin 2x)(sin 2x) $. A hint for the manipulation: use the formula for $ sin (x + y) $.

Answer (score 3):

No : $\sin^2(x)$ is just a notation for $\big(sin(x)\big)^2.$ Thus,
$$2\sin^2(2x)=2\times\sin(2x)\times\sin(2x)\neq4\times\sin(2x)\times\sin(2x).$$

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but it is close. Instead, $2\sin^2(2x)$ is the same as $2\sin(2x)\sin(2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can linearise as $$\frac{1-\cos 4x}2.$$